# error al llamar a clase mailable en laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy llamando a una clase de tipo Mailabe en un controlador. la misma me funciona en local,
en produccion no encuentra la clase y me da el siguiente error:

Error
Class 'App\Mail\contactoMailable' not found

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mail\contactoMailable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ContactoController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'nombre' => 'required',
            'correo' => 'required|email',
            'numero' => 'required'
        ]);

        $correo = new contactoMailable($request->all());
        Mail::to('test@gmailcom')->send($correo);

        
        return redirect()->route('pagina.inicio')->with('info', 'Mensaje Enviado');
    }
}
```

el index.php tiene casi igual a la configuracion default solo cambia una carpeta previa a los archivos:

```
require __DIR__.'/../proyecto/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../proyecto/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Seguro que la clase contactoMailable la tienes en la siguiente ruta: App\Mail\ ?

Comment: sii @OscarPortillo esta en la carpeta App\Mail\ esto solo pasa en produccion en local no tiene ese problema

Comment: haz un composer dump-autoload